# How do I prevent the collapsing of this child element?

Tags: html, css, parent-child, margin

I have problems trying to find how to prevent a child element from collapsing. Here is my simple code:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<htm>
    <head>
        <title>01</title>
        <meta charset="UTF-8">
        <link href="normalize.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css">
        <link href="style.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css">
    </head>
    <body>
        <div id="wrapper">
            <h1>TEXT</h1>
        </div>
    </body>
</htm>
```

When I apply overflow:hidden or add padding to the "wrapper" div it goes back to the left and top margin of the page (it fixes the collapse) but the child element stays in the same place, it looks like if I have a margin-top on it.

What can I do to fix the collapsing in BOTH elements?

Thanks for the help

---

Here is the content of the style.css

```
#wrapper {
    width: 500px;
    height: 1000px;
    background-color: red;
    overflow: hidden;
}
```

And normalize.css

```
/*! normalize.css v4.1.1 | MIT License | github.com/necolas/normalize.css */

/**
 * 1. Change the default font family in all browsers (opinionated).
 * 2. Prevent adjustments of font size after orientation changes in IE and iOS.
 */

html {
  font-family: sans-serif; /* 1 */
  -ms-text-size-adjust: 100%; /* 2 */
  -webkit-text-size-adjust: 100%; /* 2 */
}

/**
 * Remove the margin in all browsers (opinionated).
 */

body {
  margin: 0;
}

/* HTML5 display definitions
   ========================================================================== */

/**
 * Add the correct display in IE 9-.
 * 1. Add the correct display in Edge, IE, and Firefox.
 * 2. Add the correct display in IE.
 */

article,
aside,
details, /* 1 */
figcaption,
figure,
footer,
header,
main, /* 2 */
menu,
nav,
section,
summary { /* 1 */
  display: block;
}

/**
 * Add the correct display in IE 9-.
 */

audio,
canvas,
progress,
video {
  display: inline-block;
}

/**
 * Add the correct display in iOS 4-7.
 */

audio:not([controls]) {
  display: none;
  height: 0;
}

/**
 * Add the correct vertical alignment in Chrome, Firefox, and Opera.
 */

progress {
  vertical-align: baseline;
}

/**
 * Add the correct display in IE 10-.
 * 1. Add the correct display in IE.
 */

template, /* 1 */
[hidden] {
  display: none;
}

/* Links
   ========================================================================== */

/**
 * 1. Remove the gray background on active links in IE 10.
 * 2. Remove gaps in links underline in iOS 8+ and Safari 8+.
 */

a {
  background-color: transparent; /* 1 */
  -webkit-text-decoration-skip: objects; /* 2 */
}

/**
 * Remove the outline on focused links when they are also active or hovered
 * in all browsers (opinionated).
 */

a:active,
a:hover {
  outline-width: 0;
}

/* Text-level semantics
   ========================================================================== */

/**
 * 1. Remove the bottom border in Firefox 39-.
 * 2. Add the correct text decoration in Chrome, Edge, IE, Opera, and Safari.
 */

abbr[title] {
  border-bottom: none; /* 1 */
  text-decoration: underline; /* 2 */
  text-decoration: underline dotted; /* 2 */
}

/**
 * Prevent the duplicate application of `bolder` by the next rule in Safari 6.
 */

b,
strong {
  font-weight: inherit;
}

/**
 * Add the correct font weight in Chrome, Edge, and Safari.
 */

b,
strong {
  font-weight: bolder;
}

/**
 * Add the correct font style in Android 4.3-.
 */

dfn {
  font-style: italic;
}

/**
 * Correct the font size and margin on `h1` elements within `section` and
 * `article` contexts in Chrome, Firefox, and Safari.
 */

h1 {
  font-size: 2em;
  margin: 0.67em 0;
}

/**
 * Add the correct background and color in IE 9-.
 */

mark {
  background-color: #ff0;
  color: #000;
}

/**
 * Add the correct font size in all browsers.
 */

small {
  font-size: 80%;
}

/**
 * Prevent `sub` and `sup` elements from affecting the line height in
 * all browsers.
 */

sub,
sup {
  font-size: 75%;
  line-height: 0;
  position: relative;
  vertical-align: baseline;
}

sub {
  bottom: -0.25em;
}

sup {
  top: -0.5em;
}

/* Embedded content
   ========================================================================== */

/**
 * Remove the border on images inside links in IE 10-.
 */

img {
  border-style: none;
}

/**
 * Hide the overflow in IE.
 */

svg:not(:root) {
  overflow: hidden;
}

/* Grouping content
   ========================================================================== */

/**
 * 1. Correct the inheritance and scaling of font size in all browsers.
 * 2. Correct the odd `em` font sizing in all browsers.
 */

code,
kbd,
pre,
samp {
  font-family: monospace, monospace; /* 1 */
  font-size: 1em; /* 2 */
}

/**
 * Add the correct margin in IE 8.
 */

figure {
  margin: 1em 40px;
}

/**
 * 1. Add the correct box sizing in Firefox.
 * 2. Show the overflow in Edge and IE.
 */

hr {
  box-sizing: content-box; /* 1 */
  height: 0; /* 1 */
  overflow: visible; /* 2 */
}

/* Forms
   ========================================================================== */

/**
 * 1. Change font properties to `inherit` in all browsers (opinionated).
 * 2. Remove the margin in Firefox and Safari.
 */

button,
input,
select,
textarea {
  font: inherit; /* 1 */
  margin: 0; /* 2 */
}

/**
 * Restore the font weight unset by the previous rule.
 */

optgroup {
  font-weight: bold;
}

/**
 * Show the overflow in IE.
 * 1. Show the overflow in Edge.
 */

button,
input { /* 1 */
  overflow: visible;
}

/**
 * Remove the inheritance of text transform in Edge, Firefox, and IE.
 * 1. Remove the inheritance of text transform in Firefox.
 */

button,
select { /* 1 */
  text-transform: none;
}

/**
 * 1. Prevent a WebKit bug where (2) destroys native `audio` and `video`
 *    controls in Android 4.
 * 2. Correct the inability to style clickable types in iOS and Safari.
 */

button,
html [type="button"], /* 1 */
[type="reset"],
[type="submit"] {
  -webkit-appearance: button; /* 2 */
}

/**
 * Remove the inner border and padding in Firefox.
 */

button::-moz-focus-inner,
[type="button"]::-moz-focus-inner,
[type="reset"]::-moz-focus-inner,
[type="submit"]::-moz-focus-inner {
  border-style: none;
  padding: 0;
}

/**
 * Restore the focus styles unset by the previous rule.
 */

button:-moz-focusring,
[type="button"]:-moz-focusring,
[type="reset"]:-moz-focusring,
[type="submit"]:-moz-focusring {
  outline: 1px dotted ButtonText;
}

/**
 * Change the border, margin, and padding in all browsers (opinionated).
 */

fieldset {
  border: 1px solid #c0c0c0;
  margin: 0 2px;
  padding: 0.35em 0.625em 0.75em;
}

/**
 * 1. Correct the text wrapping in Edge and IE.
 * 2. Correct the color inheritance from `fieldset` elements in IE.
 * 3. Remove the padding so developers are not caught out when they zero out
 *    `fieldset` elements in all browsers.
 */

legend {
  box-sizing: border-box; /* 1 */
  color: inherit; /* 2 */
  display: table; /* 1 */
  max-width: 100%; /* 1 */
  padding: 0; /* 3 */
  white-space: normal; /* 1 */
}

/**
 * Remove the default vertical scrollbar in IE.
 */

textarea {
  overflow: auto;
}

/**
 * 1. Add the correct box sizing in IE 10-.
 * 2. Remove the padding in IE 10-.
 */

[type="checkbox"],
[type="radio"] {
  box-sizing: border-box; /* 1 */
  padding: 0; /* 2 */
}

/**
 * Correct the cursor style of increment and decrement buttons in Chrome.
 */

[type="number"]::-webkit-inner-spin-button,
[type="number"]::-webkit-outer-spin-button {
  height: auto;
}

/**
 * 1. Correct the odd appearance in Chrome and Safari.
 * 2. Correct the outline style in Safari.
 */

[type="search"] {
  -webkit-appearance: textfield; /* 1 */
  outline-offset: -2px; /* 2 */
}

/**
 * Remove the inner padding and cancel buttons in Chrome and Safari on OS X.
 */

[type="search"]::-webkit-search-cancel-button,
[type="search"]::-webkit-search-decoration {
  -webkit-appearance: none;
}

/**
 * Correct the text style of placeholders in Chrome, Edge, and Safari.
 */

::-webkit-input-placeholder {
  color: inherit;
  opacity: 0.54;
}

/**
 * 1. Correct the inability to style clickable types in iOS and Safari.
 * 2. Change font properties to `inherit` in Safari.
 */

::-webkit-file-upload-button {
  -webkit-appearance: button; /* 1 */
  font: inherit; /* 2 */
}
```

Comment: Please share the content of your `style.css` and `normalize.css` as they might contain something relevant.

Comment: @Bassem I just included that code. Thanks

Comment: Hi, can you add the full style.css please?

Comment: have you tried `* { box-sizing: border-box; }`?

Answer (score 0):

Probably, is a bug generated from the default box model.

Try adding this to your CSS.

```
* { 
     box-sizing: border-box
  }
```

Answer (score 0):

`normalize.css` adds a margin of `0.67em` (top and bottom) to `<h1>` elements :

```
/**
 * Correct the font size and margin on `h1` elements within `section` and
 * `article` contexts in Chrome, Firefox, and Safari.
 */
h1 {
  font-size: 2em;
  margin: 0.67em 0;
}
```

You need to remove that added margin and your problem will be solved.

Working example: https://jsfiddle.net/5k9pg4vt/